# How can i install Serverless on a Mac?

Tags: macos, npm, serverless

I am running  `sudo npm install -g serverless`.

Error:

```
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:{"name":"@babel/pars'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/AC/.npm/_logs/2020-03-30T21_11_07_100Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows:

1. Open Windows Powershell as admin
2. `npm cache clean --force`: Clear cache

If you are using Linux/Mac:

1. `sudo -i`: For admin privileges
2. `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: tried the above for Mac and I'm getting this error now :
npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sdk (over 30000ms)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root serverless
```